# how to create a column in select command based on other values using stored procedure in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table with 5 columns:

```
StateName DistrictName DivisionName MandalName PanchayatName
A.P        NULL           NULL          NULL        NULL
NULL       ABCD           NULL          NULL        NULL
```

Only one of the columns will have a value and remaining will be null.

Now, I want a column called PLACE which should contain the value that is not null among the above 5 columns.

Eg:

```
StateName DistrictName DivisionName MandalName PanchayatName  PLACE
A.P        NULL           NULL          NULL        NULL       A.P
NULL       ABCD           NULL          NULL        NULL       ABCD
```

I want to achieve this using a stored procedure. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `CASE` statement in the `SELECT`. Please take the sample below:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
     , CASE WHEN ISNULL(COL1, 'YES') <> 'YES' THEN COL1
            WHEN ISNULL(COL2, 'YES') <> 'YES' THEN COL2
            WHEN ISNULL(COL3, 'YES') <> 'YES' THEN COL3
END AS COL4 FROM TABLE_1
```

In my example, I have 3 columns. In your case there are 5 so add two more `WHEN`.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Um, I'm not about to do your work for you, but some quick comments:

If ONLY ONE of those columns ever have values, you might want to reconsider the database structure and have one column that signifies whether the place is a State,District,Division,Mandal or Panchayat and then another column for the name. That way you won't have any nulls at all. That will save you a lot of headaches (like this one!) in the long run.

If you don't have a choice about structure you can use COALESCE or some equivalent 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

However, that may cause problems for you if more than one column is not null (user error or database problems), but some times you don't have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Procedure_Name
@PLACE varchar(50)  
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Update table set @PLACE='ap' where StateName='A.P'


END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I dont want to update the Place. I want to retrieve the place value. The column place will not be there in the table

Answer (score 0):

If you just only 5 columns

you can use COALESCE , and Create view to do this

like this

```
CREATE VIEW HasPlaceCol
AS
(
    SELECT StateName,DistrictName,DivisionName,MandalName,Panchayatname,

    COALESCE(StateName,DistrictName,DivisionName,MandalName,Panchayatname) as PLACE

    FROM [TableName]
)
```

try it : ) . hope it's can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    StateName  varchar(10),
    DistrictName varchar(10), 
    DivisionName varchar(10),
    MandalName varchar(10),
    PanchayatName varchar(10)
)  

INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES('A.P' ,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES(NULL, 'ABCD',NULL,NULL,NULL);

select * from #TempTable

select
    #TempTable.*,
Case 
    When 
        (StateName is not null)
         Then StateName
    When 
        (DistrictName is not null)
         Then DistrictName
    When 
        (DivisionName is not null)
         Then DivisionName
     When 
        (MandalName is not null)
         Then MandalName
     When 
        (PanchayatName is not null)
         Then PanchayatName

    End as 'PLACE'

from #TempTable


DROP TABLE #TempTable
```